# How to change default style of 'title' in bibtex with style ieeetr

Tags: bibtex

I have a MWE given here

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    This concept is explained in \cite{001}
    \bibliography{biblio.bib}
    \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\end{document}
```

and my biblio.bib file is

```
@ARTICLE{001,
  author={Author 1},
  journal={Journal 1}, 
  title={Comparison between IEEE and CIGRE}, 
  year={2021},
  volume={1},
  number={1},
  pages={1-10},
  }
```

and my output pdf file content is

```
This concept is explained in [1]
References
[1] Author1, “Comparison between ieee and cigre,” Journal 1 , vol. 1, no. 1, pp. 1 −
10, 2021.
```

I want the output to come like `Comparison between IEEE and CIGRE` (IEEE and CIGRE in uppercase as in .bib file). For this I do it manually, by editing .bbl file(file created by latex). Is there other way to do without editing .bib file?

Comment: To preserve capitalization in the `.bib` file, you need to enclose the word in `{...}`.

Comment: Great...It worked for me...